# If squashing never alters committers, why does Github's squash-and-merge button update the committer?

Tags: github

In the spirit of testing the "there are no dumb questions" theory, why does Github's squash-and-merge strategy update the committer after merging a pull request?

That is, suppose I author a pull request in my fork of a project.  Suppose it has two commits in it.  Suppose I ask the project maintainer to now merge my pull request to `master` of the upstream project.

Suppose she chooses the squash-and-merge strategy so that there will be one commit at the end.

Suppose further that the merge can be accomplished via a fast-forward, i.e. as simple as possible a case as I can think of.  ([Fast-forward merges should just update the branch pointer](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---ff), which seems to me like it would leave the commit completely unchanged.)

Why is it, then, that the latest commit on `master` after the squash and merge operation features me as the author (I understand that part) but the maintainer as the committer?  Isn't that an alteration of a commit, and [doesn't squashing and fast-forward merging ensure that commits are not altered](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits)?

Is Github silently doing the equivalent of something like `git amend` under the covers?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that squashing never alters committers? I don't see anything relating to that in the documentation you reference. Squashing commits, by definition, creates a new commit. The person doing the squashing is the committer of the new commit, regardless of who committed the original commits. (Consider: the source commits may each be committed by a different person. What would happen then?)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The git documentation says, on the subject of fast-forward merges, which I thought were being used here: “In this case, a new commit is not needed to store the combined history; instead, the HEAD (along with the index) is updated to point at the named commit, without creating an extra merge commit.”

Comment: No, a squash isn't fast-forward (at least with respect to the original commits). A new commit is created from the commits being squashed.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't that an alteration of a commit

More than an alteration: a creation of a new commit, which reflect the changes of your two commits.
And your two commits are no longer referenced by the main repo: it references only the squashed commit.

That new commit has still you as an author, but is committed by the maintainer.